# AIC and model selection with multimodel

Tags: multiple-regression, estimation, maximum-likelihood, model-selection, aic

For a simple example, I am doing a multi-model regression/likelihood estimation.

The data is $(y_1,y_2,x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)$. The first model (A) consists with two regressions:

$y_1=e^{a_1x_1}+e^{a_2x_2} \ \ \ (1)$

$y_2=e^{a_3x_3}+e^{a_4x_4} \ \ \ (2)$

The second model (B) has two equations must estimated through MLE:

$y_1=e^{a_1x_1}+e^{a_2x_2}+e^{a_5x_5} \ \ \ (3)$

$y_2=e^{a_3x_3}+e^{a_4x_4}+e^{a_5x_5} \ \ \ (4)$.

> How do I do an AIC comparison of the two models?

First, the AIC of equation (1) seems to be computable by definition:

$$AIC=4-2\ln(L)$$

Second, I kind of know how to calculate the AIC of model B, which is eqn (3,4) combined. I think we need to use the multi-normal distribution for this?

However, I am not sure if it is possible **to calculate the $AIC$ of (3) by itself** and compare it with (1). This comparison has practical meanings because the $(x_1,x_2,y_1)$ is the data from individual 1, and $(x_3,x_4,y_2)$ is from individual 2.

Any hints will be helpful! You are not expected to solve anything for me.